# Getting error while running the rails server in sprockets

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, sprockets

I try to update my rails application after runned the rails app:update command i try to run rails s
but in that time, i faced some issues like

````
SassC::SyntaxError - Error: File to import not found or unreadable: font-awesome-sprockets.
        on line 8:1 of app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss
>> @import 'font-awesome-sprockets';
   ^:
  app/views/layouts/application.html.haml:14```



I tried to update the version of font-awesome-sass gem but it does not work. And added sprockets-rails gem also. 


version of font-awesome-sass : 6.3.0

version of rails : 7.0.4

version of ruby : 3.1.2

Any other ways to solve this issue?......
````

Comment: Did you look at your question after you posted it? Did you notice that it is improperly formatted and that nearly the entire thing has been left inside of a code block? You are asking strangers to take time out of their days to troubleshoot problems for you. At the very least you should put more than 30 seconds of effort into your question by reviewing it for accuracy afterwards. Additionally, phrases like *does not work* are diagnostically useless. Please read the Help Center article [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1):

The `@import 'font-awesome-sprockets';` line should be removed after update of the font-awesome-sass gem from version 5 to version 6. Keep only the `@import 'font-awesome';`

Check the [documentation](https://fontawesome.com/v6/docs/web/use-with/ruby-on-rails) and [issue #207](https://github.com/FortAwesome/font-awesome-sass/issues/207).